# .NET Azure Authentication/Authoriziation with Security Group

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, razor, azure-web-app-service

I am new to .NET C# and trying to implement the Azure authentication/authorization with Security Group. I was able to to get the authentication working, but I am not sure how to in-cooperate the Security Group within the authentication process in the Program.cs file. I did try from a number of different tutorials, but I could get it to work so I am hoping you can help me.  Let me explain how I get so far.

Please assume IT has already registered the Azure Apps and also added my account to the group called "XYZ_SecurityGroup", id = `1111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111`

Program.cs file has this code for authentication:

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration); // By default scheme is "CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme"
```

In the appsettings.json, it has this:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "domain.com",
    "TenantId": "<TenantId>",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>",
    "ClientSecret": "<ClientSecret>",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signedout",
  },
```

In the _Layout file, it has the HTML below. When I clicks that button, it will go to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID..../oauth2/v2.0/authorize` login prompt, then I login and then redirect back to the page.  This part works fine.

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="MicrosoftIdentity" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignIn"><b>Sign in</b></a>
```

The requirement is that I need to also check the user to make sure the user belongs to a specific group `XYZ_SecurityGroup` (note that user account could be in many groups) before granting access to that user.

Is there a way to authenticate and also check if the user belongs to a group at the same time in Program.cs when authenticating user?  Something like this pseudo code below?

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration); // By default scheme is "CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme"
    pseudo code ....
    check if user belongs to GroupId "1111111-1111-1111-1111-11111111111" before granting access to the app.
```